# express.js with jade templating engine

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a project that I'm and I'm trying to get the routing correct to render my jade file, golf.jade.

This is my routing.js file

```
var passport = require('passport'),
http = require('http'),
routes = require('./routes'),
user = require('./routes/user'),
game = require('./routes/game'),
golf = require('./routes/golf'),
webhooks = require('./routes/webhooks');

var mainapp = null;

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) return next();
    res.set('X-Auth-Required', 'true');
   //res.redirect('/login?returnUrl=' +      encodedURIComponent(req.originalUrl));
    res.redirect('/login');
}


function ensureAdmin(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user.canPlayRoleOf('admin')) return next();
    res.redirect('/');
}

function ensureActive(req, res, next) {
    console.log("ensuring active");
    if (req.user.active) return next();
   res.redirect("/404");
}

function ensureAccount(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user.Email) return next();
    //if (req.user.canPlayRoleOf('account')) return next();
    res.redirect('/account/externalconnect');
}

function csrf(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.token = req.csrfToken();
    next();
}

exports = module.exports = function (app) {
    mainapp = app;
    routes.setMainApp(app);
    user.setMainApp(app);
    game.setMainApp(app);
    golf.setMainApp(app);
    webhooks.setMainApp(app);


    app.get('/ping.html', function (req, res) {
        res.render('ping');
    });

    app.get('/', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, routes.index);
    app.get('/404', csrf, routes.pagemissing);
    app.get('/error', csrf, routes.error);

    //integration webhooks
    app.post("/partner/stripe/q12kp8VZLf", webhooks.stripe)

    //sports
    app.get('/:sport/week', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive,               game.week);
app.get('/:sport/coming', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, routes.coming);

//golf
app.get('/:sport/golf', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, golf);

//results
app.get('/:sport/results', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, game.results);
app.get('/:sport/results/:yr/getYearAccuracy', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, game.getYearAccuracy);

// game
app.get('/:sport/game/:id', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, game.game);
app.get('/:sport/game/:id/info', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, game.getGame);
app.get('/:sport/game/:id/details', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, game.getGameDetails);
app.get('/:sport/game/:id/results', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, game.getGameResults);
app.get('/:sport/game/:id/predictions', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, game.getGamePredictions);
app.get('/:sport/game/:id/history', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, game.getGameHistoryForTeams);
app.post('/:sport/game/:id/unlock', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, game.unlockgame);

// season
app.get('/:sport/season/:yr/weeks', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, game.getSeasonWeeks);
app.get('/:sport/season/:yr/weeks/current', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, game.getCurrentGameWeek);
app.get('/:sport/season/:yr/week/:wk', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, game.getGameWeek);
app.get('/:sport/season/:yr/week/:wk/predictions', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, game.getGameWeekPredictions);
app.get('/:sport/season/:yr/week/:wk/accuracy', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, game.getGameWeekAccuracy);
app.get('/:sport/season/:yr/team/:id', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, game.getTeamSeason);
app.get('/:sport/season/:yr/week/:wk/unlocks', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, game.getGameUnlocksForUser);

// profile
app.get('/profile', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, user.profile);

app.get('/profile/data', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, user.getprofile);
app.post('/profile/save', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, user.saveprofile);

// subscription
app.post('/profile/subscribe', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, user.subscribe);
app.get('/profile/subscriptions/available', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, user.getsubscriptions);
app.get('/profile/subscriptions/current', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, user.getusersubscription);

// billing
app.get('/profile/billing/current', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, user.getbillinginfo);


// registration
app.get('/register', csrf, user.register);
app.post('/registeruser', csrf, user.registeruser);

//forgot password
app.get('/forgot', csrf, user.forgot);
app.post('/resetaccount', csrf, user.resetaccount);
app.post('/updatepassword', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, user.updatepassword);

// login
app.get('/logout', csrf, user.logout);
app.get('/login', csrf, user.login);
app.post('/login', csrf, function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        if (!user) {
            req.session.message = [info.message];
            return res.json({ result: { code: 2, title: "Invalid login", message: "The username and password combination are not recognized. [" + info.message + "]" } });
        }
        req.logIn(user, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            return res.json({ result: { code: 0 } });
            //return res.redirect('/');
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});

};
```

My app.js file is the main file for my epress project which references this file. I am new to the node.js/express.js with jade templating.  I'm hoping to figure out what I need to change or add to get the routes to work correctly. I have a golf.jade template in my views folder that I'm trying to link to.

Hoping to figure this out soon I have looked and tried almost every tutorial I can find, looking for direction, Thanks in advance

__Scott

Comment: Where are you rendering `golf.jade`, I couldn't see it in the code? And what error do you get in doing so?

Comment: I just get a 404 error in the browser.   I'm trying to render the gold under the

Comment: --sorry --- I'm trying to reference the golf page at //golf app.get('/:sport/results', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, golf);

Comment: You are using golf as a middleware function here. Have you defined it somewhere? If not, and you just want to render this, your code should be something like `app.get('/:sport/results', csrf, ensureAuthenticated, ensureActive, function( req, res ){ res.render('golf', contextObj)});`

Comment: I will give this a try...Thanks!

Comment: I added this still not working, I'm wondering if I need to reset the app on the test server to see changes made in the javascript. Then I will see.

Comment: Yes, you always need to restart the app whenever you have made changes to your server side files e.g. app.js, route files etc.

Comment: Ok, that's what I figured...Thanks. I'll let you know